# Can a worksheet ActiveX ComboBox work on a Mac?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, activexobject, excel-2019

I have worksheet ActiveX ComboBoxes in my file (Excel VBA 2019) that are not working on a Mac computer. Is there any way that I can get these to work on a Mac?

I know I can use Form Controls that will work on a Mac, but a Forms ComboBox doesn't allow me to center the alignment of the text in the drop-down.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveX is an obsolet old Windows technology that is not available on Mac and is recommended to avoid in Windows. Further sources: [Enable ActiveX on MacOS?](https://superuser.com/questions/1548155/enable-activex-on-macos)

ActiveX is known to have many bugs and cause many strange issues in Windows. I would stay away from it as far as possible and use alternatives.

The solution is using Form Controls.

Comment: Thanks, Pᴇʜ. That will have to do. I find it strange that Excel hasn't updated these objects.

Comment: @PaulMartin They didn't because ActiveX is a dead technique. They are just there for compatibility reasons to old versions.